# Bring selected shape into view

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following VBA code in MS Word 2010.

It is supposed to step through a document, find a shape, and give me the option to delete it.

The selected shape doesn't show in the viewer window, so when asked if I want to delete a shape, I can't see that shape.

```vb
Sub ShowShapes()
Dim myRange As Range
Dim msgTrap As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim sPrompt As String
Dim myDots As Shape
For Each myRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    Do
        For Each myDots In ActiveDocument.Shapes
            myDots.Select
            sPrompt = "Do you want to delete this?"
            msgTrap = MsgBox(sPrompt, vbYesNoCancel, "Images")
            Select Case msgTrap
                Case vbYes
                    Selection.Delete
                Case vbCancel
                    MsgBox "Cancel was clicked.  Exiting Routine", vbCritical, "CANCEL"
                    Exit Sub
                'Note that Case vbNo is not listed.  That is because as the only other option
                'the routine will proceed to End Select when vbNo is clicked.
            End Select
        Next
        Set myRange = myRange.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until myRange Is Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

I tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

After `myDots.Select` try `ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView Selection.Range, True`

Answer (score -1):

Try: myDots.ScrollIntoView

BTW your code has a logic problem. It's good that you're trying to loop all the StoryRanges. But at the next level you query ActiveDocument.Shapes which means - I think, can't test as I'm on a mobile machine at the moment - you won't query the Shapes in the StoryRange you've looped to. Try using myRange.ShapeRange

Comment: myDots.ScrollIntoView won't work because ScrollIntoView applies to windows, not shapes. See my answer.